# SSIS convert DT_WSTR to date

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-warehouse

I'm new to SSIS trying to covert data types. I'm pulling data from Google Analytics and loading data into a SQL 2008 database. The date column from Google analytics appears as "DT_WSTR" and the values are in the format "20130402" (year:month:day).  I want to change the format to a date format so i can load it into a date field in my database.  How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have to use convert DT_WSTR to DT_DBTIMESTAMP. You can find BOL reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141704.aspx).

for e.g.instead of "Getdate()" use your Date_Column

```
(DB_TIMESTAMP)((DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(GETDATE()) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(GETDATE()),2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY(GETDATE()),2) + (DT_WSTR,10) Time_Column)
```

Also,  you can use the **Data Conversion transformation**, which is probably easier if you are only changing the data type.

**EDIT:** You can also look for an option of [SSIS GoogleAnalyticsSource](http://analyticssource.codeplex.com/) from codeplex.

Comment: After trial and error i used the derived column transformation with the following expression: "(DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING([ga:date],1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([ga:date],5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([ga:date],7,2))"

Im not sure if its the cleanest way but it works :-)

Comment: @resolver101 fair enough. But the options I suggested will also work.

Comment: Thanks for the responce, its apprecitaed.  I couldnt see how to following your instructions and needed a quick result.  Im fairly new to SSIS.